# ADO.NET: What API I can use to get message when SET NOCOUNT OFF

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

Many articles recommend adopting "SET NOCOUNT **ON**" to avoid receiving message like "1 Row(s) affected".

I'm curious what ADO.NET API I can use to get message when SET NOCOUNT **OFF**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SET NOCOUNT ON and reading messages using C# and ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724404/set-nocount-on-and-reading-messages-using-c-and-ado-net)

[SqlConnection.InfoMessage Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx)