# I don't know how to get print message from store procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

I wrote a store procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
      (@Num int)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Num = 1
       PRINT 'This is One';
    ELSE
       PRINT 'This is Another';
END
```

I implement in .net

```
Dim SqlCmd as new sqlcommand
DIm SqlCon as new sqlconnection

sqlcon.connectionstring =""
sqlCmd.connection =con
sqlcon.open()
sqlcmd.commandtext ="Test"
Sqlcmd.commandtype = commandtype.storeprocedure
```

I don't know how to get print message from store procedure
Please, help me.

Comment: Possible Duplication. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299797/retrieving-output-messages-from-batch-sql-command-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a SELECT statement or a RETURN

Answer (score 0):

PRINT is used to print messages on console for debugging purposes, you cannot get it as an SP result, rather you should use OUTPUT variable for this.